# submit multiple forms in django using custom html form

Tags: python, html, django

I have custom forms in the page suprated  across the page
here is my first form

```
      <form name="profile_image" class="edit-phto" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
           <label class="fileContainer">
              Edit Display Photo
              <input name="profile_image" value="" type="file" />
           </label>
     </form>
```

for profile picture
and i have another form for cover picture

```
<form name="cover_image" class="edit-phto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
      <label class="fileContainer">
         Edit Cover Photo
         <input name="cover_image" type="file" />
      </label>
</form>
```

and another form for data :)

```
<form method="post" id="infoform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
    .
    .
    .
    .
   <div class="submit-btns">
      <button type="button" class="mtr-btn"><span>Cancel</span></button>
      <button type="submit" class="mtr-btn" name="update"><span> Update</span></button>
</div>
```

and i have a form for search

```
<div class="searched">
   <form method="post" class="form-search">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search Friend">
     <button data-ripple><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
   </form>
</div>
```

i just want to submit the 2 images forms and info forms when i click update button
is there a way to do sachthing in django without using form.as_p and stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can just pass `request.POST` to each of your forms in the view and process each one as normal. However, you should be aware of conflicting names - the best way of managing this is to use form prefixes so that Django knows which bit of data relates to which form:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

Comment: they used 'form.py file' and put several form inside one class in form file, I am not sure if it help me because i dont have form file at all , I know form file would give default form look in django, i am trying to build custom html, css look

Comment: Well without using a Django form, you can simply use `request.POST.get('...')` and pick out all of the info you need to proces

Comment: I tried to do img = request.POST.get('profile_image') then print(img) it gives none since the update button submit only form data and there is nothing with that name in that form